# Dot products of columns of mixed shaped arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I'm trying to get the dot products of each element in an nx2x3 array and an nx3 array (the value of n is always shared between the two).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
b = np.arange(24).reshape(4,2,3)
```

The array I'm trying to get would contain these:

```
print(np.dot(b[0],a[0]))
print(np.dot(b[1],a[1]))
print(np.dot(b[2],a[2]))
print(np.dot(b[3],a[3]))
```

I'm sure there's a way to use `einsum` or `tensordot` for this but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `einsum` this way:

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,ikj->ik', a, b)
array([[  5,  14],
       [ 86, 122],
       [275, 338],
       [572, 662]])
```

All that's happening here is axis 0 of `a` is multiplied with axis 0 of `b`, and axis 1 of `a` is multiplied with axis 2 of `b`. Values along the latter axis are summed and a 2D array is returned.

(`tensordot` doesn't apply itself neatly to this particular problem as we need multiplication along *two* axes and summation along just *one*. These operations only come in pairs with `tensordot`.)

Comment: Or simply `(a[:, None] * b).sum(2)`.

Comment: Yes that would also work well. I'm in the habit of using `einsum` because it avoids creating the larger-than-necessary array before summing along an axis.

Comment: einsum certainly does the trick in this case. I had done it manually
    <code>prod = b * np.expand_dims(a,axis=1) 
    dots = np.sum(prod,axis=2)<code> 
Feel free to speed check but I would wager einsum is faster